# Handing Serial Port DataRecieved event when havign a method to handle reply from serial port at the same time

Tags: c#

I have a class to handle Serial Port communication. I have registered to the DataRecieved event of the port, So when the event triggers ill send the string back..

```
public SerialPort Port { get { return _port; } }
_port.DataReceived += DataRecieved;

private void DataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        string result = _port.ReadExisting();
        BytesReceived?.Invoke(this, result);

    }
```

And i have a method that send string to the seeial port and then return the reply.

```
 public string ConnectSendRead(int readTimeout, string message)
    {
        if (!_port.IsOpen)
            return null;

        _port.WriteLine(message);
        Thread.Sleep(readTimeout);
        return _port.ReadExisting();
    }
```

The problem is when i am using the `ConnectSendRead` method, The event triggers and im using `_port.ReadExisting();` and then when calling it again in `ConnectSendRead` method, Its returning an empty string

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is not that reliable solution.

Comment: You cannot use both DataReceived and ReadExisting, you must pick one to read.  Since you wrote the ConnectSendRead() to always return the reply, you do not have a use for DataReceived.  And avoid ReadExisting, you need to be sure that you got the full reply.  How to do that is not obvious since you didn't document the device protocol.  If you're lucky then ReadLine() gets the job done.

Comment: There are serval cases in which i wait for a specific string at the device startup for doing some operation so I have to register to the event. And I still need the option to send a string and return the answer. Is there no solution to that case?